# javax.faces.convert.Converter in a multitenacy environment

Tags: java, multi-tenant, converters

I've got a problem with my custom converter.

```
@FacesConverter(value = "converterObjet")
public class ConverterObjet implements Converter {

    private static Map<Object, String> listObjet = new WeakHashMap<Object, String>();

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
        synchronized (listObjet) {
            if (!listObjet.containsKey(entity)) {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                listObjet.put(entity, uuid);
                return uuid;
            } else {
                return listObjet.get(entity);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uuid) {
        for (Entry<Object, String> entry : listObjet.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(uuid)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

the problem is the static Map.

as I use a schema per tenant

```
@Entity
```

@Multitenant(MultitenantType.TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@TenantTableDiscriminator(type=TenantTableDiscriminatorType.SCHEMA, contextProperty="tenant-id")
public class Contry implements Serializable {

the hashCode() is the same for all tenant countries which have the same id

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime+ this.idpays.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }
```

I  use the converter in my XHTML pages like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu widgetVar="wvCtrcdt" id="contry"
    height="150" value="#{candidatView.contryChoosen}"
    converter="converterObjet" filter="true">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{text['chxInit']}" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItems value="#{contryView.listcontry}" var="contry"
        itemLabel="#{contry.contryname}" itemValue="#{contry}"></f:selectItems>
    <p:ajax update="PoBirth" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

the contryChoosen returned by the converter is not from the current tenant because it considered as already exist in the map as it has the same id of the country of the first tenant.
the question is how can I custom my converter, so it can differentiate tenant country, even if they has the same id?

Comment: Than make the I'd unique by adding a tennant prefix to it when you put it in the map. This is all effectively not a JSF issue but a generic  'problem' in java as well...

Comment: Yes you absolutly right. and that what I did !